# Database design without a 1 column table

Tags: ms-access, database-design, database-normalization

I have been working on a database design and I'm stuck hitting a wall. I'm ending up with what I'm reading is not a normalized database structure but I'm having issues trying to find a "more correct" design and if this design is acceptable how do I execute it in Access?

TLDR: If a table with a single column set as an auto number is an acceptable design, how do you go about inserting a record in it using Access?

The segment of the database of concern is creating a structure for storing companies. Requirements for this is that any changes need to be approved by another user and all historical changes need to be captured so that it can be easily reverted also a company can have multiple aliases but only one legal name.

There is three tables in my solution but one of them is a single column table. From what I've read 95% of people on stack overflow all think its a very bad idea but I've found one post were people are that there are cases for it. I think this is not normal also because I can't find a way to just create a new record in a table with only an auto number column (In Access I have not tried others yet).

Table Structure

1. Company Names : ID, Company ID, Is Legal Name, Created By, Created On, Approved On, Approved By, Event ID, Is Active
   (A company could have a few different names known to the public: TD vs Toronto Dominion. Each name is inserted here with a reference to the company it belongs to)
2. Companies : ID (Auto Number)
   (A company exists and this is its ID)
3. Companies History : ID, Company ID, Market ID, Holding Company ID, Created By, Created On, Approved On, Approved By, Event ID, Is Active
   (These are the historical changes that have been made to the company and who did them and who approved them)

Column Notes:

Event ID : is a FK reference to a table holding each record of actions that have either created, updated or deleted records. (User Research using method [y], Typo Fix, ...)

Is Active : Since deleting records is not possible (historical records need to be kept) this column is used to track if this record is to be included in queries.

Options I see and their issues:

I could get rid of the companies table and make Companies History : ID be the new company id but I find that in that case each time I want to update a company I would need to update each FK reference to the previous company id (I don't think this would be a very normalized approach)

Another Option I see is that I get rid of Companies table and use Company Names : ID as the company id and I would add a column to Company Names called Alias of Company ID. I find that solution adds a log of complexity to my stored data where an alias has company information that differs from the entry that was aliased.

Another Option is that I could add the columns: Created By, Created On, Approved On, Approved By, Event ID and Is Active but this would be duplicating information found in the first record for this company in the Companies History table and this isn't adding any real description to this record.

Anther Option is that I make the Companies table a mirror of Companies History and that when I update or insert a record in Companies I would also insert a record Companies History. With this solution I find that again I duplicate information, that newest record in "Companies History" would hold the same information found in last Inserted or Updated record in in Companies

Another option but is to replace the Companies : ID auto number with a short text and I just get the hash of the current timestamp + a random int. I can now insert new records into this table using access but I feel that this is overkill since I just need the exact same functionality as the auto number.

Another option is move only the legal name into Companies table but now when the legal name of a company changes I have no way of tracking this. Also if I want a list of all names I need to use a union on Companies and Company Names. I find that using unions can reduce performances of queries and I use them only when explicitly needed.

If I don't want to duplicate any information and I don't want to update all FK it seems that I need a table with a single column. If this is acceptable how do I go about inserting a record into a table with a single column set to auto number in Access.

Comment: Thanks for enumerating options, but please make this more precise & concise. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular-formatted base table initialization. PS What does this have to do with normalization? The term does not mean "good design" or "without duplicated data".

Comment: Please ask one specific question re one specific thing. Not a bunch of questions or one plus "if so/not then ...". Also we can't tell you what is "best" for you until you define it--say how to map inputs to a choice.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  `Companies` can be derived from `CompanyNames` (`select distinct CompanyId from CompanyNames`), there is no point storing again that information. Just replace that table by a view if you want it (but it as little added value).

On the other hand, if `CreatedOn` refers to the Company creation (not the row creation) then it is obviously a property of the Company, and I would rather work with
`Companies` --> `Aliases`.
But of course I don't know the ins and outs of the reality you're dealing with.

Comment: Would you suggest using "Select max(CompanyId)+1 from CompaniesNames" to get the next company id? If CreatedOn was the companies creation date I would need to still put it in history to handle the case that a user needs to fix a typo. Company started/created in 1990 not 90 (needs to be tracked). The history table is used to track user changes and not changes that a company my experience (the two are very close subsets)

Comment: Do you  *need* consecutive numbers for CompanyId ? If not just, you can default the CompanyId to the value of `CompanyName.ID`, and change date if not the initial CompanyName you're adding.

Comment: Can't use CompanyName.ID because a company can have multiple names and they can all be added as a batch. But I like your initial idea of dropping the table and adding a layer of management for CompanyNames.CompanyID. Using "SELECT DISTINCT ..." to replace the dropped table and "SELECT max(CompanyID)+1 ..." to get a new companies ID. I'll wait a little longer and if no better alternative solutions are presented I'll accept your answer.